# Batch || I am having problems loading variables from txt file

Tags: file, batch-file, readfile

I am having problems reading from text files.
When I try to load in variables from text files, they just return blank, but when I 'type' them, they return perfectly normal.

The code I use to read and save the files (basecd is the directory of the bat file):

```
:loadGame
cls
echo Saves:
cd Data\Saves\
dir /a:d /b
echo[
cd %~dp0
echo %~dp0
set /p filename=Name of save file: 
echo[
if "%filename%" EQU "" (
echo File does not exist...
pause
goto menuLoop


)
if exist "Data/Saves/%filename%" (
    cd %basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\
    echo %basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\
    echo Loading File...
    set /p name=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\name.txt
    set /p race=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\race.txt
    set /p hair=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\hair.txt
    set /p eyes=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\eyes.txt
    set /p area=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\area.txt
    set /p quest_starter=<%basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\quest_starter.txt
    type %basecd%Data\Saves\%filename%\area.txt
    echo %name%
    echo %quest_starter%
    echo %area%
    echo File loaded
    pause
    goto mainLoop

)

echo File does not exist...
pause
goto menuLoop
```

This is the code that I use to write to the files, but I can see on my computer that the files are in the folder and are not empty.

```
:event_generic_save_game
cls
echo Save file name:
:saveloop
set /p filename=    
if "%filename%" EQU "" (
    echo File name is invalid!
    goto saveloop
)

if exist "Data\Saves\%filename%" (
    echo Save file already exists. 
    set /p input=Overwrite? y/n 
    if "%input%" EQU "n" (
        echo Save canceled
        set /p buffer= 
        cls
        goto mainLoop
    )

)

echo saving game '%filename%'...

if exist "Data\Saves\%filename%" (
    del Data\Saves\%filename%
)
mkdir Data\Saves\%filename% 
echo %area%>Data\Saves\%filename%/area.txt
echo %hair%>Data\Saves\%filename%/hair.txt
echo %eyes%>Data\Saves\%filename%/eyes.txt
echo %race%>Data\Saves\%filename%/race.txt
echo %name%>Data\Saves\%filename%/name.txt
echo %quest_starter%>Data\Saves\%filename%/quest_starter.txt
echo Game saved
pause
cls
goto mainLoop
```

'set /p buffer=' Is a stand in for 'pause'

Please help, I have been ruminating on this for days and I can't get over it.
   Thank you for reading

Comment: You could minimize code blocks if you revert the `if exist ...` to `if not exist ...` for the `echo File does not exist...` without any var it doesn't matter being eclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `\` is the path-separator in batch, and `/` introduces swiches. *Sometimes* batch does the translation. Not always....

This has nothing to do with your apparent problem. Please see endless items on SO about `delayed expansion`

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

In your case, you are varying the values within the block, hence you see the **original** values, not the **altered** values.

Tip for game-generation:

If you reserve a character as a prefix for variables-you-want-to-save (eg all variables I want to save/reload start with `#`) then all you need to *save* a game is

```
set #>"mygamefile.txt"
```

and all you need to *reload* a game is

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("mygamefile.txt") do set "%%a"
```

To zap all `#` variables (useful before reloading a game) use

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
```

Comment: Don't miss the space between usebackq and delims.

Comment: @soja : AFAIAA, the space is optional. Could you provide an example of where it is required?

Comment: All spaces in the option string are optional, but for the sake of readability I recommend to insert them...